# How do I join a subquery in the from clause?

Tags: sql-server

I need to find a way to link the v_FullCollectionMembership table to this query so I can filter by department

```
select ARPDisplayName0, count(*) as Total,
v_FullCollectionMembership.Name
from
(
select 

       CASE WHEN ARPDisplayName0  like 'Bomgar%'  THEN 'Bomgar' 
       ELSE ARPDisplayName0  END ARPDisplayName0
       

       from v_gs_INSTALLED_SOFTWARE

        where 
        (ARPDisplayName0  like 'Bomgar%' and
        ASCII(left(ARPDisplayName0  , 1)) between ASCII('A') and ASCII('Z')

) as SoftwareTitle

inner join
v_FullCollectionMembership on v_FullCollectionMembership.ResourceID = SoftwareFilter.ResourceID


where v_FullCollectionMembership.Name = 'Human Resources'
group by v_FullCollectionMembership.Name, ARPDisplayName0
```

I've tried to join using the common field "ResourceID", but it just comes up empty.

Comment: I don't believe this code would even compile.  Your subquery is named 'SoftwareTitle', but your join expects 'SoftwareFilter'.  Even accounting for that error, you are joining on 'ResourceID' but don't output such a field in the subquery.  I imagine you've tried to simplify the query, but you went too far doing that if the code wouldn't even compile.  Also, a **small** set of sample data in the form of sql statements is definitely needed to even begin addressing your question.

Comment: `I need to find a way to link the v_FullCollectionMembership table to this query so I can filter by department` Unclear what that means because we have no information on what these tables/views are and how to join them. Your query certainly has quite a few manifest errors: missing column, incorrect alias, missing/extra bracket, strange (and nonsensical, given the previous code) filter `ASCII(left(ARPDisplayName0  , 1)) between ASCII('A') and ASCII('Z')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite syntax mistakes above, and not providing any results, this is what I found to be the answer

```
select 
Name, 
ARPDisplayName0, count(*) as Total

from
(
select CASE WHEN ARPDisplayName0  like 'Bomgar%'  THEN 'Bomgar' 
       ELSE ARPDisplayName0  END ARPDisplayName0,
       ResourceID
       
from v_gs_INSTALLED_SOFTWARE

where  ARPDisplayName0  like 'Bomgar%' and
       ASCII(left(ARPDisplayName0  , 1)) between ASCII('A') and ASCII('Z')

) as SoftwareTitle
inner join
(
select v_FullCollectionMembership.ResourceID,
        v_Collection.CollectionID,
        v_Collection.Name
        
from    v_Collection
        inner join
        v_FullCollectionMembership on v_FullCollectionMembership.CollectionID = v_Collection.CollectionID

where   v_Collection.Name = 'Human Resources'
    
) as CollectionName

on SoftwareTitle.ResourceID = CollectionName.ResourceID

group by ARPDisplayName0, Name
```

Answer (score 0):

is n't it ?

```
SELECT ARPDisplayName0, 
       COUNT(*) AS Total, 
       FCM.Name
FROM   (SELECT CASE
                  WHEN ARPDisplayName0 LIKE 'Bomgar%'
                     THEN 'Bomgar'
                  ELSE ARPDisplayName0
               END ARPDisplayName0
        FROM   v_gs_INSTALLED_SOFTWARE
        WHERE  ARPDisplayName0 LIKE 'Bomgar%'
               AND LEFT(ARPDisplayName0, 1) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN BETWEEN 'A' AND 'Z'
        ) AS ST
        INNER JOIN v_FullCollectionMembership AS FCM 
           ON FCM.ResourceID = ST.ResourceID
WHERE   FCM.Name = 'Human Resources'
GROUP   BY FCM.Name, 
           ARPDisplayName0;
```